# How can I send a JSON string to an ASP Web API method with a POST?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I am sending a JSON message to a MVC method. When I debug it calls the method but 
it seems like the data is not there. In other words answerDetail is null.

Can someone give me some advice on what I may be doing wrong. Here's what I have:

The following MVC Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("CheckAnswers")]
public void CheckAnswers(AnswerDetail2 answerDetail)
{
    var a = answerDetail;

}
```

This message is sent to the method:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:81/api/Question/CheckAnswers HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:81
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 722
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:81
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:81/questions/5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=4puG_e0..B181

[{"answerId":5,"text":"<p>x</p>","correct":null,"response":false},
 {"answerId":6,"text":"<p>xx</p>","correct":null,"response":false},
 {"answerId":7,"text":"<p>xxx</p>","correct":null,"response":false}]
```

Here's my AnswerDetail2 class:

```
public class AnswerDetail2
{
    public int answerId { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> correct { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> response { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:** Please note I changed the header. It's actually going to a Web API method so I think it's okay to post an object. The problem is it's not getting accepted.

Comment: Did you mean to say `POST` instead of `PUT`? Also, your POST data is an array of `AnswerDetail2`, not a single instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U r passing a json string but the paramater u have taken is a class. This wont work.

Try this instead.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("CheckAnswers")]
public void CheckAnswers(string answerDetail)
{
    var a = answerDetail;
    //deserialize ur json string..
}
```

and u r 'POST'ing the data. R u making an ajax POST method?

try this

```
var myObject =
{
    answerId: 123,
    text: "my Text",
    correct: true,
    response: false,   
};

var answerDetail = JSON.stringify(myObject);

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: <Controller>/CheckAnswers,
data: answerDetail,
success: function(data){
  //what ever
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send your requests by ajax with `PUT method` not by form